# Display on laptop doesn't work if I connect it to a monitor first

Tags: linux, xrandr, display, awesome

### Background Information

- **Laptop:** Asus ROG G46V
- **System:** Debian Linux version 8 Jessie
- **Windows Manager:** Awesome WM
- **Desktop Environment:** N/A

### Problem

When I start my laptop with VGA monitor plugged in, the built in laptop monitor goes blank and **xrandr** commands will not fix it (extend the monitor), it just stays black.

However my system works fine if I:

1. Disconnect my monitor before booting up
2. Plug in monitor after booting into awesome wm
3. Run the appropriate xrandr command to extend the monitor.

   **xrandr --output eDP1 --auto --output VGA1 --mode 1024x768 --above eDP1**

This -hack- works, but it's annoying and I would prefer a solution that doesn't require me to unplug my monitor before starting my laptop every time.